# unrecognized selector sent to instance Swift NSNotification

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, instance

I watched this video on a Messaging App for Swift and copied it word for word. Yet, there have been some updates to Xcode recently so I am not sure if that is the problem or I typed something in wrong. I also looked at other questions similar to mine and still can't find the issue.

The code I putting in the viewDidLoad() deals with the showing the keyboard:

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
```

Then I call the keyboardWasShow function here:

```
 func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {

    let dict : NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let s : NSValue = dict.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let rect : CGRect = s.CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {

        self.resultsScrollView.frame.origin.y = self.scrollViewOriginalY - rect.height
        self.frameMessageView.frame.origin.y = self.frameMessageOriginalY - rect.height

        var bottomOffset : CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.resultsScrollView.contentSize.height - self.resultsScrollView.bounds.size.height)

        self.resultsScrollView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: false)

        }, completion: {
            (finished: Bool) in

            //

    })

}
```

The reason why I think it's the keyboardWasShown function because output showed **keyboardWasShown]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f848c12be40**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your suspicion is not correct.  Can you post the entire error message?

Comment: If you actually look at the error message it will give you a lot of information.  You omitted the start of it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  You omitted the complete error  message.

Comment: My suspicion was correct. Sorry about not posting enough information. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method you implemented takes an argument so you need to add a colon to the end of the selector name.

```
 let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
 center.addObserver(self, 
                    selector: "keyboardWasShown:",
                    name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification,
                    object: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks rdelmar! That did it. Is that new or something that's been around for awhile? This is the first time Ive seen that.

Comment: @JackB03 This has been around forever in Objective-C. As far as I know it's been there since the beginning of Swift as well. In Objective-C, the colon is part of the name, so someMethod and someMethod: are two different methods.

Comment: Thats great to know. Again, Thank You!